# ng build: How to set the number of retries for ES5 bundles

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My dev-build always retries 3 times. I'd like it to fail immediately (no retries).

In [angular-issue #16520](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16520) an error message shows that it fails after the 1st retry:

> Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading... An unhandled
>   exception occurred: cancel **after 1 retries**!

How can we set the max number of retries for ES5 bundle generation?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should change the retries count.
I resolved this issue by downgrading the **@angular-devkit/build-angular** to **0.801.2**

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.801.2
```